# Replace just one occurrence of a sentence and wrap it with style

Tags: javascript

My goal is to find a sentence in a html page and replace it / wrapping with 
`<span class='red'>...</span>`

basically the same concept of highlighting results...but instead of words i need to highlight an entire sentence

for some reason my code sometimes works, sometimes not...

here:

```
$('body').each( function () {
  $(this).html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace(myString, '<span class="red">'+myString+'<\/span>' );
  }); 
});
```

also it seems to stop when it finds the first occurence of the first word of the sentence...
any help?

Comment: You have multiple BODY elements? `:P`

Comment: And the sentence could be anywhere in the page? (Like, in the title, in the footer, in the navigation menu). Or is there a wrapper element for the text you want to perform your search for?

Comment: I can restrict the wrapper element, i set 'body' just as an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use a regexp
- Add "g" to replace all occurences
- Use "$1" to reuse your string
- Be carefull there is no special caracter in your string (that could be iterpreted as a regexp operator)

  ```
  var re = new Regexp('('+myString+')', "g");
  html.replace(re, '<span class="red">$1<\/span>')
  ```

Answer (score 0):

ok, let's try this, using recursion:

```
var html = $('body').html(); 
function replaceHTML(haystack, needle, replacement, position){
   var index = haystack.indexOf(needle);
   var newHaystack = haystack.replace(needle, replacement);
   if(index > - 1){
      return replaceHTML(newHaystack, needle, replacement, index);
   } else {
      return haystack;
   }
} 
$('body').html(replaceHTML($('body').html(), 'string you want to replace', 'replacement string', 0))
```